# htaccess rewrite and 1&1

Tags: .htaccess

I'm installing a website onto hosting provided by `1&1`. It seems that `1&1` has various quirks and problems with how htaccess files run on it.

Things are not working correctly, and I've stripped down the file to the bare minimum to try and get to the base of the issue.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z]*)/?$ page.php  [NC]
RewriteRule ^listings/([a-zA-Z]*)/?$ page.php  [NC]
```

Now the bizarre thing:

Going to `http://www.essenceseeker.com/pages/example`   works

Going to`http://www.essenceseeker.com/listings/example`   does not!

The rules are identical, the only difference is the first subcategory.
There are no 'real' folders the server called 'pages' or 'listings' which may be causing conflicts.

It seems that ONLY using a subfolder called 'pages' will work - it is not just a problem with 'listings' as any other subfolder name will not get picked up.

What could possible be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^listings/([a-z]*)/?$ /page.php  [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-z]*)/?$ /page.php  [NC,QSA,L]
```

1. This needs to be placed in .htaccess file in website root folder.
2. You do not need brackets `()` if you do not plan to use that part in your rewrite rule.
3. I have added `QSA` flag to preserve any possible parameters (query string) -- like referrals, tracking id etc.
4. I have also added `L` flag to stop rewriting if rewrite occurred.
5. I have changed the rules order -- just in case, although it should not matter

Comment: Thanks - it was adding the 

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

line that did it - Didn't know about those options, I'll research into what difference they make!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your RegExp is wrong, in both cases. 1&1 maps near matches, so `pages/example` is mapped to `page.php`, as is `page1.php` to  `page.php`.

I guess the correct rule would be

```
RewriteRule ^pages/[a-zA-Z]*$ page.php  [NC]
```

Answer (score -1):

i used the following options in my .htaccess file when working with php micro frameworks such as https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree or http://flightphp.com/install

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

AddType x-mapp-php6 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```